# Equivalence of different consistency sentences

Tags: logic, proof-theory, incompleteness, provability

Take any formal system $S$ that has a proof verifier program and interprets [TC](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2495263/21820) or [PA$^-$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peano_axioms#Equivalent_axiomatizations).
$
\def\imp{\Rightarrow}
\def\con{\text{Con}}
$

Then [the incompleteness theorems](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2486348/21820) show that $S$ does not prove $\con_1(S)$, where the subscript denotes that it is based on a particular encoding of a particular proof verifier of $S$ into $S$. $S$ also does not prove $\con_2(S)$, for another choice of proof verifier and encoding. But...

> Does $S$ always prove $( \con_1(S) \imp \con_2(S) )$ (regardless of the two choices)?

I think the answer is no, because it seems I need $S$ to support induction to establish such a proof, namely I seem to need $S$ to interpret either PA or TC+I (where I is an induction schema). So...

> If my guess is wrong, how do we show that $S$ proves the equivalence?
>
> If my guess is correct, what are two choices of $\con_1$ and $\con_2$ that witnesses it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is tricky. It is equivalent to the question of whether standard Gödel sentences for $S$ produced by two different encodings will be provably equivalent in $S$.

Suppose we define a Gödel sentence to be a fixed point of a "not-provable-in-$S$" predicate, then choose a coding which determines the details of the not-provable predicate. Then the fixed points of this one not-provable predicate will be interderivable. That's elementary, well-known, and in lots of textbooks.

But that doesn't help with your question, which comes to: if we vary the not-provable predicate by varying the coding, will the fixed ponts as we vary the predicate still stay interderivable? Presumbably there will have to be *some* restrictions on what counts as an acceptable coding: but I don't know what the restrictions are. Nor do the usual (or not-so-usual) textbooks tell us, again as far as I know. Which is why [I asked a similar question at mathoverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/101660/when-are-provability-predicates-provably-equivalent): the response was "I don’t think there are any useful criteria known that would guarantee the provable equivalence of two proof predicates that would not beg the question."

I too would be delighted to know if we can do better than that!

Comment: Can you at least confirm my claim that if $S$ supports induction then we in fact have provable equivalence? My reasoning (but I was a bit lazy to formalize it) is that we ought to be able to prove within S by induction that if Con1(S) is false with proof length n then Con2(S) is false. And thanks for the link; I totally did not know that you had asked this before on MathOverflow! =)

Comment: I doubt whether the claim is true in general for PA (which has induction), unless you put some constraints on allowable codings. What constraints do you have in mind?

Comment: Hmm.. I had in mind that we start with any program that implements a proof verifier $V$ such that $V(p,x)$ always halts and outputs "yes" if $p$ is a proof of $x$ and "no" otherwise. This would vary drastically depending on the proof-style, and that also means that my attempt is doomed. We need some uniform computable interpretation of TC+I or PA with computable inverses... where "uniformly interprets" is like as defined [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1895288/21820). Oh that seems insufficient too unless $S$ is simply TC+I or PA itself, which seems like "trivial" then.

Comment: By the way, I wrote a [recent post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2564618/21820) sketching a computable procedure for extending any given $Σ_1$-sound system to one that is still $Σ_1$-sound but $Σ_3$-unsound. As I ask in my comment, can this be improved? I gave a non-constructive argument in my answer, but I doubt it can be made constructive. Any ideas?

Comment: Hmm do you think I should post my other question on MO?