# Is Peano arithmetic consistent in predicate logic? If so, what are the implications?

Tags: predicate-logic, incompleteness, peano-axioms

Peano arithmetic can't prove its own consistency, as proven by Gödel's incompleteness theorem. Many seem to think that this means that it is possible that Peano axioms are inconsistent.

However, if the Peano Axioms are formulated in predicate logic, it seems as though they are satisfiable. From that it follows that they are consistent. Thus it's impossible to ever prove anything contradictory from the axioms in predicate logic. (Is this correct?)

So since that is so, should we not accept that the axioms in fact are consistent? It seems to me that no matter what is proven/provable from the axioms, the result/thorem must still be consistent. How should one think about this distinction?

Comment: While not an exact duplicate, see [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2207370/21820) for why you have no choice but to believe PA is consistent if you wish to even use basic FOL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to say that a collection of axioms is satisfiable, you must provide a model satisfying them. It certainly *appears* that standard arithmetic satisfies the Peano axioms, but can you *prove* it? Can you even prove that it makes sense to talk about "standard arithmetic"? It's not even obvious that infinite sets exist, without an axiom saying they do! Can you show that there isn't a largest integer, without assuming something equivalent to the Peano axioms?

The thing is, if you can provide a *finite* model satisfying a set of axioms, you can check the axioms directly and thus prove that they're satisfied. For example, to show that the set of sentences $\{a < b, b < c\}$ is consistent, all we have to do is provide the example of three objects $a$, $b$, and $c$, and a relation stating $a < b$ and $b < c$. But Peano Arithmetic has no finite models, so we can't provide anything so directly inspected. In principle, it could be that we've completely misunderstood how the natural numbers work, and that Peano's axioms don't actually hold of them.

Now, most mathematicians take it as assumed that $PA$ is indeed consistent, because it's inconvenient to assume otherwise, but it is definitely possible that a contradiction is provable from $PA$.

As to the distinction "in predicate logic": the Incompleteness Theorem is *about* predicate logic. Moving to predicate logic doesn't free you from Incompleteness, it puts you right in the crosshairs.

Comment: Aha, so then the claim that sat(Peano-Axioms) is wrong (or at least hasn't been proven)? Does the completeness theorem say that it can't be proven?

Comment: @Dole Hasn't been proven and can't be, not without assuming something stronger than PA.

Comment: @Thank you!! So just to make 100% sure that I understood, the completeness theorem states that PA can't prove a theorem stating its own consistency, and in addition it can't be proven that the axioms are consistent in predicate logic? Or are the two simply the same thing?

Comment: @Dole PA is an *extension* of predicate logic - it's a set of axioms that operate in addition to the usual deduction rules of predicate logic. So anything provable in predicate logic is provable in PA (though many things provable in PA are not provable in predicate logic).

Comment: Are you talking about theorems? Because the way I would prove consistency of an axiom set in predicate logic is not by using the deduction rules (i.e. crafting theorems) but by simply producing a model that satisfies the axioms. But as far as I understand Godel says a theorem that states the consistency can't be produced. This distinction leads to my confusion...

Comment: @Dole Producing a model is not working within predicate logic. Predicate logic is a formal system; it can only work by deduction. Producing a model is meta-mathematics. The problem is that without a formal system, we can only prove what we can see and touch - we can't even show that there are infinitely many numbers, because we can't directly examine each of them. It's deductions that let us conclude things like that. You're correct that Godel's Incompleteness states that a theorem claiming consistency can't be proven, but this is a *big* deal, because that's the only way we could get it.