# Do "assert" and "prove" mean the same thing?

Tags: soft-question, definition

I'm reading a book, and this book says "if no two asserted statements of this theory contradict each other" this got me super confused for some reason, and so I asked this question [Consistency definition](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3547537/consistency-definition) and now I understand that "asserted statements" mean "all the statements that are provable"
so I googled "asserted" and here https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/assert it says that assert and prove are synonyms while in other dictionaries (Merriam Webster, Cambridge etc) it does not.

P.S. I'm not sure if I should have asked this question on math StackExchange or the one for languages, but since we're talking about math maybe it has a slightly different meaning.

Comment: That link says *prove* and *show* and *point to* are associated words for *assert*, but they need not be synonyms.  Here they are not synonyms for "state firmly that something is true"

Comment: @Henry https://www.macmillanthesaurus.com/assert "Synonyms: To **show** or agree that something is true"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In natural language, "asserts" and "proves" mean very different things; an assertion need not come with a justification, while a proof *is* a justification. *In this specific context*, however, "asserts" is being used synonymously with "proves:" when the author says that a theory *asserts* something, they mean that the theory *proves* that thing. **This can be (and has been here) confusing to someone new to the topic, and in my opinion was a bad linguistic choice here.**

It's worth noting that sometimes "thinks" is also used this way (e.g. "The theory $T$ thinks that $*$ is commutative" is slang for "$T$ proves $\forall x,y(x*y=y*x)$"), as is "says." This is all part of a general rhetorical device of *anthropomorphizing* theories which **after** some initial experience this language can actually be helpful (although of course this is subjective), but I would say it should be avoided early on.

Comment: That's the answer I was looking for, thank you!